# Problems setting up dynamic columns in an angular-ui-grid

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to setup a angular-ui-grid with `x` columns depending on how many objects `view.trend.getTagsList()` returns. `$scope.addData()` is a functions that invokes once every three seconds

```
        $scope.columns = [];


        $scope.setGridColumnWidth = function () {
            return (100 / view.trend.getTagsList().length + 1) + '%';
        }

        $scope.redoColumns = function () {

            $scope.columns = [];
            $scope.columns.push({
                displayName: 'TimeStamp', field: 'x', width: $scope.setGridColumnWidth(), sort: {
                    direction: uiGridConstants.DESC,
                    priority: 1
                }
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < view.trend.getTagsList().length; i++)
                $scope.columns.push({ displayName: view.trend.getTagsList()[i].getTitle(), field: 'y' + view.trend.getTagsList()[i].getId(), width: $scope.setGridColumnWidth() });
        }


        $scope.addData = function () {

            if (view.trend.getTagsList().length > $scope.columns.length) {
                $scope.redoColumns();
            }

            $scope.tslab_grid.data = view.trend.getTagsList()[0].getData();
        };

        $scope.tslab_grid = {
            enableGridMenu: true,
            enableColumnResizing: true,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            multiSelect: false,
            enableRowHeaderSelection: false,
            paginationPageSizes: 18,
            paginationPageSize: 18,
            enableVerticalScrollbar: 0,
            enableHorizontalScrollbar: 2,
            columnDefs: $scope.columns,
            data: null
        };
```

Now as test I only try to fetch a single object `view.trend.getTagsList()[0]` with its list of data `.getData()` which contains a list of `{ x: Date, y: value }`.

My question is why doesn't angular-ui-grid rewrite the columns as in `$scope.redoColumns()`? I get displayNames to 'X' and 'Y' in chrome instead of TimeStamp and whatever `view.trend.getTagsList()[i].getTitle()` is. Also want to add that there's no 'default' sorting on field: 'x' either.

Comment: Try to put the call in a $timeout : $timeout($scope.redoColumns, 0); // behaves like a queue

Comment: @Steffomio didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$scope.redoColumns = function () {
    var c = [];
    c.push({
        displayName: 'TimeStamp', field: 'x', width: $scope.setGridColumndWidth(), sort: {
            direction: uiGridConstants.DESC,
            priority: 1
        }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < view.trend.getTagsList().length; i++)
        c.push({ displayName: view.trend.getTagsList()[i].getTitle(), field: 'y' + view.trend.getTagsList()[i].getId(), width: $scope.setGridColumnWidth() });

    $timeout(function(){
        $scope.columns = c;
    }, 0);
}
```

Comment: I can now see that redoColumns() is invoked, but first it says it doesn't recognize $timeout then when removed I get: TypeError: newRawData.forEach is not a function  at Grid.modifyRows....

Comment: Sorry, thought it's self explained that you have to add $timeout into your controller-header.

Comment: Still getting: `TypeError: newRawData.forEach is not a function at Grid.modifyRows...`

Comment: First I cant find newRawData in your code. Second have you tried to add data on initialization like: "$scope.columns = []; $scope.redoColumns();" Because redoColumns() looks like an eventhandler for me.

Comment: redoColumns() is event driven why is that bad?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just removing the `$scope.columns = [];` in `redoColumn` function

Comment: Put your $scope data always in one big object to avoid those problems. For example $scope.data.columns = []. Now you can replace columns without causing problems. Second + for doing so is, you avoid code-chaos and can link all controller $scope data with one $scope.data = data; in your controller.

Comment: I just wanted to empty the $scope.columns array. As you can see its also declared outside the function in the bigger object.